# can't install git on ubuntu virtual machine

Tags: git, ubuntu

Right after I installed ubuntu on my VM I tried to install git. But I get unmet dependencies error so I tried:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
```

Then I got the error:

> add-apt-repository: command not found

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

But is saying that is already the newest version.

My steps:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

> The following packages have unmet dependencies.
>   git: Depends: liberror-perl but it is not installable
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
```

> sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties
```

> software-properties-common is already the newest version.
>   python-software-properties is already the newest version.

Comment: What were the steps you took to install git?

Comment: I follow the oficial git installation on: git-scm.com/download/linux

Answer (score 4):

To install git on Ubuntu, you should run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git-core
```

Then check the install worked by typing

```
git --version
```

Comment: I updated but when I try to install git-core I get: The following packages have unmet dependencies. git-core: depends: git (>1:1.7) but is not going to be installed. E:unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Are you able to install any other packages besides git?

Comment: Since you are getting unmet dependencies I would recommend checking out this answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/142808/222926 It explains how to fix a broken package sources list. You could try running `sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install -f` to attempt to 'fix' the broken dependencies.